# Are questions that clairify API documentation helpful and therefore a good fit for the site?

Tags: discussion, questions

I would like to make two initial assumptions.

1. Clearly written and explicit documentation saves time.
2. Programmer time is usually the most expensive component in a software project.

As an example of assumption #1, if documentation clearly states expected behaviour of an application, then a programmer would not need to expend the time and effort necessary to draft a test of the application to discover how it actually works.

As to assumption #2. I do not offer any specific examples, yet at university this is a prevailing notion.

In the Help Center > Asking, it states that

> "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers ... if
>   your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by
>   programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to
>   software development."

Furthermore, in the Help Center > Asking "How do I ask a good question," it states

> "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague."

So, if we agree that my two assumptions above are most often true, and that StackOverflow exists in part for (potentially) busy professional programmers, then are questions that clarify documentation indeed welcomed on this site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions *asking* to clarify API documentation are certainly welcome.

That being said, make sure you actually *ask a question*. If you know the answer, go ahead and self-answer, but don't put the answer in the question.

Self-answered questions are prone to.... quality issues, so please make sure you are making a high quality post if you go that route.

Comment: Is there a specific tag that should be used for these sorts of questions?

Comment: @not__p The tag associated with the API. If you are asking about MSDN documentation, tag with C#/VB/F# and the appropriate version of .NET (if its version specific) I don't see a lot of value in a [tag:documentation] addition